# MongoDB is blocking my project on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pythonanywhere

MongoDB is blocking my project on PythonAnywhere. This is because the IP address is different. I need a solution on how I can allow mongoDB to accept requests coming from PythonAnywhere. I have already tried to allow access from all IPs but I'm still getting an error.

Below is the error, I'm getting from PythonAnywhere.

```
File "/home/kaymapalo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 259, in _select_servers_loop
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: ac-azn1hc8-shard-00-01.voifniy.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms),ac-azn1hc8-shard-00-00.voifniy.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms),ac-azn1hc8-shard-00-02.voifniy.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 65c7e303c81ca1b232fdfb16, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('ac-azn1hc8-shard-00-00.voifniy.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-azn1hc8-shard-00-00.voifniy.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-azn1hc8-shard-00-01.voifniy.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-azn1hc8-shard-00-01.voifniy.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-azn1hc8-shard-00-02.voifniy.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-azn1hc8-shard-00-02.voifniy.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>]>
```

I've tried allowing access from all IPs, but that's not working.

Comment: *"This is because the IP address is different."* I don't see any IP address in your post.

Comment: Well, I tried running it locally running with a VPN and it gave the same error not until I turned the VPN off. So I'm guessing MongoDB somehow is blocking other IPs and only allowing the IP I used when creating the database.

Comment: It this case it wouldn't be programming issue and therefore off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: "Connection refused" isn't a blocked IP.  That error means your connection attempt reached the destination IP, but the machine at that IP did not have any process listening on the port you were trying to connect to.  A blocked IP will simply not respond to the packet, so you would get a connection timeout.

Comment: @Joe "Connection refused" is the result of an RST packet, which can come from everywhere in the path even the client machine. It is completely possible that the IP is blocked by a firewall with action REJECT.

Comment: If you're using a free account, you will not be able to connect to an external db, due to internet restrictions.  You can use default MySQL db provided by PA, or consider upgrading your account, if you want to use external services without restrictions.

Comment: @caseneuve thank you very much I'll consider that